# Breaking Long SED String

Tags: bash, sed

How would I break a long sed line, for example:

```
sed -n 's/.*<a href="\(.*\)" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Download<\/a>.*/\1/p'
```

I would like to have something like this for example:

```
sed -n 's/.*<a href="\(.*\)" target="_blank" 
  rel="nofollow">Download<\/a>.*/\1/p'
```

I know about "\" but its not working for sed. Thank you.

Comment: Why? Most people's terminals can do > 80 chars these day...

Comment: Yes, but I like to keep my scripts under 80 this makes it easier when using 80x24 terminal and nano =) Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a workaround with multiple variables. Its not perfect but it works. Here it is in case any one else is having simular issues. If any one finds a better solution please share here.

```
str1='<a href="\(.*\)" target="_blank"'
str2='rel="nofollow">Download<\/a>'
sed -n "s/.*$str1 $str2.*/\1/p"
```

Another way would be to use heredoc, which is a bit cleaner way.

```
str=$(cat <<'EOF'
<a href="\(.*\)" target="_blank" \
rel="nofollow">Download<\/a>
EOF
)

sed -n "s/.*$str.*/\1/p"
```

Alright, I've also found that printf could be used like this but you need to escape double quotes.

```
str=$(printf "<a href=\"\(.*\)\" target=\"_blank\" \
rel=\"nofollow\">Download<\/a>")

sed -n "s/.*$str.*/\1/p"
```

The cleanest way is this.

```
str="<a href=\"\(.*\)\" target=\"_blank\" \
rel=\"nofollow\">Download<\/a>"

sed -n "s/.*$str.*/\1/p"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break it on the shell level rather than the sed level:

```
sed -n 's/.*<a href="\(.*\)" target="_blank" '\
'rel="nofollow">Download<\/a>.*/\1/p'
```

Unfortunately that doesn't allow indenting the second line.

Comment: Yeah this works too. Also if you need space between target and rel variables in a link you can do target="_blank" '\ Note the space between double quotes and single quote. I've tried this method before, but instead with indentation before rel variable which did not work ofc. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to extract string(url), not substitue. How about drop sed and take grep? it would be short!

```
grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*' file
```

example:

```
kent$  echo 'foo<a href="IWantIt" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Download</a>baz'|grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*'
IWantIt
```

Comment: those where just examples =) I need to know how to split inside sed. So your examples are irrelevant to my question but thanks.

Comment: @Tux I didn't see "split" in your sed line. Just saw you "break" your line into two. btw, your question was tagged as `bash`, I think grep is also involved. but sorry for disturbing.